# color correcting scans

Tags: post-processing, lighting, photo-editing, software, troubleshooting

I got an Epson ff-680w but can't find any way to color correct the scans using a calibrated profile. My understanding is that this is the main thing to look out for when trying to scan in archive quality. How would I build a color calibration profile and apply that to the scanned images?

Comment: Do you have a reference chart & profiling software?

Comment: @Tetsujin - I have the i1 Profiler by xrite and need to buy the reference chart. If I buy the reference chart and create the profile, how would I color correct?

Comment: Since you have I1Profiler, do you also have a printer and I1Pro spectro? There are ways to make scanner profiles with Argyll software. They are pretty easy to use. You attach them to the scanned image then convert to sRGB or Adobe RGB in Photoshop.

Comment: @doug [Please put your answers in the answers section, even if they're short](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4655/please-put-your-answers-in-the-answers-section-even-if-theyre-short). Thanks!

Comment: @PhilipKendall It isn't clear that the OP has the tools to make scanner profiles which is why I asked. If he does, which is probably unlikely, then I can post an answer. Otherwise it wouldn't be helpful.

Comment: @Doug Understood - but as they haven't responded in a week, I'd suggest just putting it in an answer anyway and it can always be edited/deleted later if it's not relevant.

Comment: @PhilipKendall -This answer most likely addresses the OP's needs if he doesn't have a spectro and printer and most don't. https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/83998/archival-scanning-calibrating-scanner

Answer (score 1):

You need a target for the type of calibration you want to do, either transmissive or reflective. You can find a list on X-Rite's website, or select the one you have in i1Profiler under "Scanner Profiling" in the Workflow Selector; the list is in the dropdown is labeled "Target Type". If you got a target with an X-Rite bundle that included i1Profiler, it's likely a ColorChecker 24 or 5G.

You can select the right one, and the software will walk you through creating a profile for the scanner and type of scan.

To apply the profile depends on the software you use to scan, but most software has the ability to apply a profile to the process. If you have images that were scanned earlier, you can use "Apply Profile" in Photoshop to adjust them.

Answer (score 1):

This describes a program I wrote that produces highly accurate scanner profiles. At least for CYMK printed material. Less so for scanning photos from chemical processes due to significant metameric errors intrinsic to most scanners. It corrects for a major source of scanner errors (large area crosstalk) and it also provides tools for using i1Profiler and printed targets to create scanner profiles.

[How to Fix (when needed) Scanner "Large Area Spatial Crosstalk"](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/103036/how-to-fix-when-needed-scanner-large-area-spatial-crosstalk/103037#103037)